# Wortbildungstechniken

Tags: neologism

Lately, I’ve come across a never-seen-nor-heard-before word in a German article (https://kritischeperspektive.com/kp/2019-02-facebook-des-mullmanns-bester-freund/):

> So gilt für Facebook beispielsweise die gezielte Beleidigung „Bitch“ (Schlampe) als unproblematisch, doch das Wort „Dyke“ als absolut unzumutbar. Im Englischen bezeichnet dieses Wort eine Lesbe, wobei der Begriff **unserorts** auch mit „Kampflesbe“ übersetzt werden könnte, also die gemeinhin als unangenehm wahrgenommene Frau, die Frauen liebt.

I looked this word up (unserorts) in Duden and online as well, but Google showed its ’no result’ message. Though I understood what it meant contextually, I’m wondering if words like this could be made up as ’Neologismen’ (here are only a few of my ideas for new words in German):

> ***Gebrauchs** (G) eines Handys können wir unsere Freunde anrufen.* = Using a mobile phone, we can call our friends up.
>
> *Es wird **nutzens** (G) dieser Firma, wenn dieses Produkt in größeren Zahlen verkauft wird.* = This company will make a bigger profit if this product is sold in bigger quantities.

That these may sound outlandish and totally ungrammatical for a native speaker, I know. If there's anything better, could you list up some of them? I would like to know if there are some neologies that reset the rules for German grammaticality.

Comment: _Unserorts_ sounds analogous to existing words such as _allerorts, ander((e)n)orts, außerorts, geeignetenorts, hierorts, innerorts, manchenorts, vielerorts,_ or _zuständigenorts,_ maybe formed as a contamination with _unsererseits._

Comment: I don't know what you googled, but "unserorts" gives me 211 hits. Not many, but certainly not 'no result'. May be due to your language settings.

Comment: Yout second examples makes no sense. Your first one is understandable how you get there, but how would you form the second one in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't inventing new words here, but new grammar. That's beyond what you should do if people should be able to understand you.

---

***Using** a mobile phone, we can call our friends up.*

That's a *present participle*. German has those, too:

> Ein Handy **gebrauchend** können wir unsere Freunde anrufen.

The meaning is very similar to the English structure but no one talks like this in German. Instead, people just say:

> Mit einem Handy können wir unsere Freunde anrufen.

Where's the verb? It's gone. German speakers don't hesitate leaving out filler verbs as *to use*.

---

Your second example is just overcomplicated. What makes you hesitate saying:

> Es wird dieser Firma **nutzen**, wenn dieses Produkt in größeren Zahlen verkauft wird.

Because that's a perfectly valid German sentence.

---

I think you are barking up the wrong tree. *Unserorts* is an adverb made from a a noun and a counter or adjective as a modifier prefix, not from a verb. The building rule for these is very straightforward:

> alle + Ding → allerdings
>
> viele + Seite → vielerseits
>
> nötig + Fall → nötigenfalls
>
> anders + Fall → andernfalls

Comment: Your example "Ein Handy gebrauchend..." could be part of a manual or from a telltale. There this form is used more often.

Comment: FWIW, in English, you can also say *"with a mobile phone we can call our friends (up)"*. There the *using* is also replaced by *with*